# Regular Spaces with $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

> Take a regular topological space. Let $C$ be a closed set and $x\in C^C$. Prove (or show a counterexample) that there are always two sets $A,B$, both open, with $C\subset A\in \tau$ and $x\in B \in\tau$ with $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$.

Clearly, we can have $C\subset A\in \tau$ and $x\in B\in \tau$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and so $C\subset A\subset B^C$. This implies $\overline{A}\subset B^C$ and $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$. Similarly $B\cap \overline{A}=\emptyset$. This seems to be as far as one can get and makes me think there must be a counterexample.

Comment: Must A,B be open?

Comment: Yes, they are both open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I was able to prove it just now! Let us continue from where the question ended with $C\subset A$ and $x\in B$ and $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$. Clearly, $x\not \in B^C$ which is a closed set. So there are two disjoint open sets with $B^C\subset W$ and $x\in Y$ with $Y\cap W=\emptyset$.

I say that $Y$ and $A$ are the required sets. $Y\subset W^C\subset B$ and this means (because $W^C$ is closed) that $\overline{Y}\cap \overline{A}\subset W^C\cap \overline{A} \subset B \cap \overline{A}=\emptyset$.